# App starts and the device screen goes black sometimes

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is a very strange bug. I'm running my app on an iPhone device and only sometimes, when the app starts, you can see the app for a freckle of a second and then the screen goes black.

Any advice?

Comment: You must be doing some task i.e. DB or Network related on the main thread. But still you need to post more information about your startup tasks to verify the claim.

Comment: Startup you mean, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Comment: yeah that is one piece to start, another is your first viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

- If you have call any thread or block the main thread to be execute, then for some second your screen will be blank. To avoid that add some splash screen shot, like FaceBook shows. Replace Default launch images. Default is blank, so it shows black screen. If you make required size screen shots then it will not shows black screen when app launch.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly why this happens but I develop an app and testing on several devices like 4, 4S,5,5S(iOS 7.1, 8.1) and get same black screen as you get after I change device. My solution is always "quit from simulator and open it again" when I do like this it works fine (Sometimes 3-4 times). I guess there is nothing to do by user. My thought, Only apple can solve this problem if we lucky :)